# Excepción por longitud

Tags: java, excepciones

Estoy programando en java  i tengo una duda sobre como puedo crear una excepción del tipo NumberFormatException en un setSerialNumber(serialNumber) que me muestre un mensaje de error cuando los digitos introducidos sean mayor de 12?

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Para qué lenguaje? php? java? c#?

Comment: Tu pregunta es de muy mala calidad, debes añadir un poco más de información en ella, ¿de que lenguaje de programación hablas? ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Hola , gracias por vuestra respuesta he editado la pregunta añadiendo un poco más de información, estoy investigando crear una excepción con NumberFormatException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La excepcion NumberFormatException se usa cuando intentas parsear un String a un Int por ejemplo:

```
    String s = "Hola";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

No tiene seentido utilizarlo en tu caso creo.
Si lo que quieres es crear una excepcion de todas formas prueba a crear tu mismo la excepcion, pero no uses NumberFormatException

Para mi la solucion correcta seria controlar la longitud del numero en el setter :

```
  int tamaño = String.valueOf(numero).length();
  if (tamaño > 12){
       // HACER ALGO
     }
```

Comment: gracias! lo he solucionado como tu me has aconsejado, me habia centrado en algo que no tenia sentido !